# Need to align text in middle of cell in Latex table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to place text center (both horizontal or vertical) in cells in a table in latex (see last picture). The funny thing is, that the code works in an online editor, like `https://www.papeeria.com`, when I use the TeXLive 2016 distro, but not in the newest distro 2019. It does not work in texmaker. And I have reinstalled texmaker and LaTeX.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left =0.85cm, right= 0.85cm, top = 1.55cm, bottom = 1.55cm}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}


\usepackage{array}    % for the first table

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} % <--- color cell in table





\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|N}
            \hline 
            \cellcolor{orange!50} \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text &
            \\[85mm]
            
            \hline
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text &
            \\ [85mm]
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    \newpage
    
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|N}
            \hline 
            \cellcolor{orange!50} \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text &
            \\[85mm]
            
            \hline
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text &
            \\ [85mm]
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

I get this:
[image]

But i want this:

[image]

Comment: Drop the `\\[85mm]`, that is adding 85mm space below your line.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the idea is that they have to look like the last foto. Im using them as flashcard in my class for my students. What else can I do to make them look like the last pciture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an empty column with a defined height to fake your vertical height. The following replaces your (unused, why did you add them?) `N`-type column with `H{85mm}`, which is a vertically centred column that's 85mm high.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left =0.85cm, right= 0.85cm, top = 1.55cm, bottom = 1.55cm}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\newcolumntype{H}[1]{@{}>{\rule{0pt}{#1}}m{0pt}@{}}


\usepackage{array}    % for the first table

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} % <--- color cell in table

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|H{85mm}}
            \hline 
            \cellcolor{orange!50} \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text &
            \\
            
            \hline
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text &
            \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \newpage
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|H{85mm}}
            \hline 
            \cellcolor{orange!50} \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text &
            \\
            
            \hline
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text &
            \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want that effect for every row of your table, you can switch back to your old `N`-type columns and use an explicit `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` in them to set the height of that row.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was driving me crazy :-) Thanks for your help, and Happy New Year to you :-)

Answer (score 2):

`\parbox` allows you to specify the height and internal alignment, which `p{}` columns and their varients do not.  You need the collcell package to use them.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left =0.85cm, right= 0.85cm, top = 1.55cm, bottom = 1.55cm}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} % <--- color cell in table

\newcommand{\mycolumn}[1]{\parbox[c][85mm][c]{\myarg}{\centering #1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\def\myarg{#1}\collectcell\mycolumn}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|M{5.1cm}|}
            \hline 
            \cellcolor{orange!50} \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text \\
            \hline
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text &
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text & 
            \huge Text \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tabularray` package, then your text will automatically be vertically centred:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, hmargin=0.85cm, vmargin=1.55cm}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
          vlines,
          hlines,
          colspec={XXXXX},
          rows={ht=8.5cm,halign=c,font=\huge},
          cell{1}{1}={bg=orange!50}
        }
            Text & Text & Text & Text & Text\\
            Text & Text & Text & Text & Text\\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]